# captureScreenShotOnFailure for IE in selenium

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

is it possible to use captureScreenShotOnFailure for IE? maybe some kind of hacking that i can do to enable the function to also run on IE?

Thanks
Dee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the code that you suspect may fail in a 'try' block, and then add the screenshotting code in its corresponding 'catch'. Essentially the same as what is done [here](http://code.google.com/p/gibble/source/browse/trunk/gibble/src/test-end-to-end/java/net/chazzwazzer/gibble/gui/CaptureScreenShotOnFailure.java?spec=svn62&r=62).